# MongoDb aggregate domunets fields and merge

Tags: mongodb, merge

I have some document saved with this structure

```
{
   some_key: { 
        param1 : "val1",
        param2 : "val2",
        param3 : "val3"
        param4 : "val4"
        param5 : "val5"
   }
}
```

"some_key" field can contains some or all fields

I have one of this document for every user on every day

```
user 1, day1

{
   some_key: { 
        param1 : "val1",
        param2 : "val2",
        param5 : "val5"
   }
};


user2 day 1
{
   some_key: {
        param5 : "val5"
   }
};


user1 day2
{
   some_key: { 
        param1 : "val1",
        param3 : "val3",
        param5 : "val5"
   }
};


user2 day 1
{
   some_key: { 
        param1 : "val1",
        param4 : "val4",
        param5 : "val5"
   }
};
```

i need to obtain a merged documents and obtain for every param the medium or the sum of the values

like this

```
{
   some_key: { 
        param1 : "medium or som params1",
        param2 : "medium or som params2",
        param3 : "medium or som params3",
        param4 : "medium or som params4",
        param5 : "medium or som params5",
   }
};
```

Comment: Is `some_key` a constant, is there a limited set of keys, or can the key be anything? Are `param1` to `param5` also a limited set of constant, or can they, too, be anything?

Comment: "some_key" is a costant. Param1 to param5 can they,too, be anything